# Remove Decimal Separator from Money

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query :

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(987654321 AS money), 1)
```

Now the result is :

```
987,654,321.00
```

But i want to get :

```
987,654,321
```

I want to do this in my query, what should i do?

Comment: Mabe give us contect? My standard answer would be "why the heck do you go varchar to start with in the SQL level and not in the application level?".

Comment: @TomTom Yes, i know that i can do this in the application level, but i need it here, because of some reasons!

Comment: Also [please stop specifying `varchar` without defining the length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server money data type does not have decimal separators.  It is a binary structure in the database.  It seems you may want to convert a money data type to an integer in T-SQL and add separators.  In that case try:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(987654321 AS money), 1), '.00', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely not do this, but this will work if you absolutely need it:

```
DECLARE @value varchar(50)

SET @value = CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(987654321 AS money), 1)
SELECT  LEFT(@value, len(@value) - 3)
```

this will return `987,654,321`

Comment: I agree with @bencripps its not recommended approach!